# Jquery .ready not working properly for items in partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is my function:

```
  $().ready(function() {
    console.log('DOM is ready');
    var songtoload = $(".soundcloudid").first().html();
    console.log(songtoload)
    if (songtoload == undefined) {
      console.log('Hide the widget');
      $("#sc-widget").hide();
    }
    if (songtoload !== undefined) {
      console.log('Show the widget');
      $("#sc-widget").show();
    }
  });
```

For some reason, songtoload keeps coming up as "undefined" even when I get the following response in the Chrome console:

```
$(".soundcloudid").first().html();
"31204641"
```

Am I incorrectly using .ready?

**EDIT**
The purpose of this is to only show the SC player widget if a song is present in the playlist partial

Comment: how about what the rest of us uses : `$(function() { ...`

Comment: can you show the html of `soundcloudid`?

Comment: I don't know, but I am curious to why you are using == and then !== instead of !=  .. or === and !==

Comment: I guess you have to check undefined like this.`if(typeof songtoload != 'undefined')`

Comment: `html()` will return an empty string if there is no HTML, and not undefined ?

Comment: @adeneo will it be undefined if the element doesn't exist? in 1.7.1 it returns `null` if no element is selected.

Comment: @KevinB - seems using `first().html()` returns undefined if the element does'nt exist ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uJL7k/4/)). But then just using .length (see below) would be a better option.

Comment: Can the people that downvoted let me know why so I know what I did wrong?

Comment: I upvoted you to counter the downvote because I saw no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the songcloudid objects are loaded dynamically... the checks to toggle the widget should be moved to the function that dynamically loads these objects.:

```
function refreshPlaylist() {
    // ... some code to refresh it
    $.ajax({
        // your ajax call to refresh it
        success: function (data) {
            // ... load your data first and put it on the page
            var $songToLoad = $('.soundcloudid:first');
            if ($songToLoad.length == 1) {
                console.log($songToLoad.html())
                console.log('Show the widget');
                $("#sc-widget").show();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Hide the widget');
                $("#sc-widget").hide();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This is helpful so I don't have to deal with undefined, but it has the same problem where it always hides the widget even if there is an element returned by $('.soundcloudid:first');

Comment: It hides even if there's an element returned? So your log shows both "Show the widget" and "Hide the widget"? If so, that would mean it's being called multiple times or there is another script somewhere that hides the widget after this script executes.

Comment: the console shows just "Hide the widget" but if I copy the function and paste it into the console, it shows the widget. Also, if I enter just $('.soundcloudid:first'); in the console, it returns [
<td class=​"soundcloudid" style=​"display:​none;​">​31204641​</td>​
]

Comment: This means that the .soundcloudid is not present on the page when the page is loaded.  What loads the partial? If the partial is already on the page then I can see why you think it's the document.ready(). But if the <td> is loaded dynamically somehow, then you need to check after it's loaded.

Comment: The partial is loaded onto the page by a jquery function called refreshPlaylist. To make sure it loads when this page does, I use   $(refreshPlaylist); Is there a way to implement on the function I'm doing on success?

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty sure that's your problem.  Inside your success function you should put everything that's in the ready block.  I'll update my answer to show it.

Answer (score 0):

`$().ready` will wait until the result of `$()` is ready. `$()` is an empty set. What I believe you want would be either `$(document).ready(function() {...})` or its shortcut: `$(function() {...})`